# Why does my PC get stuck in boot loop w/ no POST after restarting?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, hardware-failure, reboot, desktop-computer

Recently I upgrade my case and began using a new SSD. Whenever I restart, the PC gets stuck in a boot loop and doesn't POST. After about 5 attempted boots it shuts down. After this happens, if I turn the surge protector off and on then start the PC it works properly. It also works properly if I shutdown instead of restart and just start the computer.

<s>The issue is not related to Windows 10 and the system worked properly before replacing the case.</s> The case and SSD were replaced at the same time, so the SSD could be conflicting. However, It seems to be an issue with the PSU or MB, but does anyone know which to check first or if it may be a different issue?

Edit 1: SSD and Case were replaced at the same time.

Edit 2: ***PC Specs***-

- i7 3770 (3.40 GHz)
- 16 GB DDR3
- Intel H77 Chipset
- EVGA SuperNOVA 850G2 PSU
- EVGA Geforce GTX 970 Superclocked
- NZXT Phantom 820 Full-Tower Case
- 1 SSD (Specs I can get in a couple hours)
- 2 TB HDD (Data)

Comment: Are you running the most current BIOS for the motherboard? You say "*I upgrade my case and began using a new SSD*" and then say "*...not related to Windows 10 and the system worked properly before replacing the case*". So was the SSD new to the configuration or not?

Comment: It is the most current BIOS. The SSD was indeed new to the configuration, so could it be related to the new SSD conflicting with Windows 10?

Comment: It sure could! When doing these types of upgrades, you have to consider all components and connections. I'd suggest going over everything again. As it stands, you have not given enough information for us to help. Add some details about your motherboard, SSD, case, etc. so we can try to offer specific help.

Comment: Also, are you able to boot to a CD or DVD of some sort, like a Ubuntu Live CD? Or USB?

Comment: The PC boots with no problem so yes, the issue only comes up after a restart. I'm editing my post with the PC specs.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is the SSD, Windows doesn't like being copied.

Comment: That is better. I have retracted my vote to delete. It is great you are willing to help others. To improve how you do that, please read [How do I write a good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help]. This will help you understand Super User better.

Comment: I updated with specs. Considering it has no problem with booting and flipping the surge protector off and on then booting, wouldn't it seem to be related to power? If it's an SSD issue, what steps should I take first?

Comment: The surge protector is likely coincidental. What did you use to move windows to the new drive?

Comment: I installed it from scratch on the new SSD then moved data over but if everyone thinks thats what it is, then I'll move the data back and reformat.